# Problema al compilar map con scssphp

Tags: css, sass, scss

Estoy intentando compilar este map de scss mediante la siguiente herramienta: https://leafo.net/scssphp/docs/

```
$breakpoints: (
    'mobile': ( min-width: 900px ),
    'small': ( min-width: 1100px ),
    'medium': ( min-width: 1400px ),
    'large': ( min-width: 1600px )
) !default;
```

Compila todo lo demás correctamente (de hecho, si borro todos los elementos del map compila), pero con ese map me aparece el siguiente error:

```
assets/scss/components/../__variables.scss on line 1 in \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php:4051
Stack trace:
#0 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(2739): scss_parser->throwParseError()
#1 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(1654): scss_parser->parse('$breakpoints: (...')
#2 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(608): scssc->importFile('assets/scss/com...', Object(stdClass))
#3 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(639): scssc->compileImport(Array, Object(stdClass))
#4 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(511): scssc->compileChild(Array, Object(stdClass))
#5 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(1662): scssc->compileChildren(Array, Object(stdClass))
#6 \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php(608): scssc->importFile('assets/scss/com...', Object(stdClass)) in \dev\inc\class\class.scssc.php on line 4051
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna posible idea de lo que puede estar causando el error? Hasta donde sé, la sintaxis está correcta. ¿Puede que sea problema del compilador?